# JavaFX FXML - Does Button have OnEdit Like Method?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have a class that extends `Button` where a `String` is constructed like so,

```
text = button.getText();
```

However, I need to always update text when it changes i.e. a listener. Does Button have a method like onEdit where I can make sure the button's text is always the same as the variable text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a listener with the button's text property:

```
button.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
    // do whatever you need with newText
});
```

Comment: I would want this in the constructor so each instance has the listener correct?

Comment: @FamousFrik I was just going from the code you posted. That will register the listener so that if the text of `button` changes, the code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

What constructor are you talking about? The constructor of your derived Button?

Another question is, where your text-variable or -field resides? If it is in your derived Button-class there is no need for it, since you always have access to the original text-property and your text will always reflect the same content as the Button's text-property - even from the outside world.

If you want to process the changed text for some reason you should trigger the processing with the change-listener passing the new value along to a consumer-method without storing it redundantly in your class.
So the

> // do whatever you need with newText

of the proposes solution should probable look like

```
doIncredibleThings( newText );
```

you might even trigger some asynchronous action if necessary in order not to block the event-dispatch-thread too long.

Comment: A few suggestions - Your post was automatically reviewed because it starts with a question. It's not a *great* idea to do that. You are only 4 rep away from being able to comment on questions to ask for follow-up information.  Until then, and especially with this case, I think it's fair just to state your *assumptions* about the question.  You've done that, but it looks more like a question than an assumption.  Try to get rid of the question marks.  It's a good thing to shoot for in any answer. Thanks!